# How to terminate the script once the EOF of input file is reached?

Tags: bash, stdin

I have to take input from a file for the script:

```
  $ ./script < input.txt
```

My script runs an infinite while loop and you can come out of it only by pressing `ctrl-d`. How to add `ctrl-d` to input.txt so that script.sh automatically terminates when it encounters it.

```
 while true;
 do
   echo 'blah blah'
   read i      # takes from file 
   case $i in
   a ) 
          echo 'blah blah'
          read j #takes from file 
   .......
   *)     echo 'invalid option'
          continue
      ;;
   esac
 done
```

This loop should go on until the user presses ctrl-D or end of input.txt is reached.

Comment: More like stackoverflow question, what is your script look like. Usually you just end your file

Comment: what exactly your script is doing ? reading the input.txt ? how you are reading the file ?

Comment: 神秘德里克 - it goes on into `case *)` and runs the loop infitely and the script does not terminate on its own. I think the best way to come out of loop is feed ctrl-d to loop somehow (or put ctrl-d at the end of input.txt)

Comment: @MelB, there is no such thing as an End-Of-File *character* in a Linux/UNIX filesystem; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389581/5419599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read` in your `while` condition:

```
while read -r a; do
  echo 'blah blah'
  case "$a" in
    a)
      echo 'blah blah'
      read -r b
      echo "line: $b"
      ;;
    *)
      echo 'invalid option'
      continue
      ;;
  esac
done
```

This will exit the loop once end of file is reached.

Comment: great ! I don't know how but it worked.

Comment: `while` repeats the loop until the `read` after it cannot read any more lines

Comment: Piotr Sawicki's solution also works but it always gives this warning stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see, what Your script does in the first place. When You read a file like that, then You can read the content of a file with a *while* loop:

```
while read p; do
   echo $p
done <&0
```

The loop will assign one line of a file to a variable *p* at once. Notice the redirecting operator at the end of the loop - it redirects the stdin.

Comment: I can't do that because input is given multiple times within one iteration

Comment: @MelB To be honest I did not get Your point, as in the example You have shown, you will provide the script with one file at the time. In such case, you can use solution I gave.

Do You want to run this script continuously, and feed one process with many files, in some period of time? Or maybe check, if the file is updated and process some new data?

Comment: This will only read one line of the input file in one loop. Please see the code posted above.